# Create MBTiles file from PostGIS database tables

Tags: postgis, mbtiles

I am trying to create MBTiles files from PostGIS database connection. It should contain all geometry objects in .mbtles file (not only a tileset objects for browser).

What is the simpliest way to connect to a PostGIS database and put all the objects in a .mbtiles file?

I tried Martin, Tippecanoe and pg_tileserv, but it just doesn't work...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.